# Empty flutter project after creation with Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am experiencing a problem with flutter creation using Android Studio.

I have flutter SDK in place:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.592], locale en-NZ)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.36.0)
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Nevertheless, Android studio does nothing after creation. So I manually open the project and it is empty.

[image: Project folders]

The project structure shows NO SDK.
[image]

Don't know how to fix this. Please help!

Comment: The Project Structure shows No SDK correctly because this is an Android SDK, not Dart/Flutter one.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

As it turned out my Dart SDK settings got erased.

What should help:

1. Go to Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Dart;
2. Enter your path to Dart SDK. It is located at `%your_flutter_sdk%/bin/cache/dart-sdk`. Make sure that proper version is displayed under this path;
3. Enable Dart support for this project by checking it;
4. Save changes and restart Android Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with something like this:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2443

Answer (score 0):

Do not install Flutter in a directory like C:\Program Files\ that requires elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was selecting `Use android.* artefacts` when creating the Project.

Hope that works for anyone else. Manually adding the Dart path as Vsevolod describes did unfortunately not generate the files. The path was indeed empty, but adding one and reloading Android studio did nothing.

[image: creating project]